# How to document a class as member of namespace

Tags: webstorm, jsdoc, jsdoc3

```js
// in some file
/**
 * @typedef myspace
 * @property {Object} models
 * @property {Object} services
*/

// in other files

/** @typedef myspace.models.ModelA */
class ModelA { ... }

/** @typedef myspace.models.ModelB */
class ModelB { ... }

/** @typedef myspace.services.ServiceA */
class ServiceA { ... }
```

How to define classes with JSDoc if I want to make them as members of the namespaces `myspace.models` and `myspace.services`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need using [@namespace](https://jsdoc.app/tags-namespace.html) and [@memberOf](https://jsdoc.app/tags-memberof.html), I believe